# Visual Studio 2022 error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after trying to create new project on asp .net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2022

[image]

After Installing Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.3.4 I have tried to create new new project on asp .net web application(.NET Framework)(c#), but it is not working as you can see it constantly saying object reference not set to an instance of an object. I have tried to run it as administrator. I have done most of the things I have found on the internet but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp no, this is Visual Studio tooling throwing that exception. OP: just don't create new .NET Framework projects, use .NET 6. Have you tried updating/restoring Visual Studio?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have repaired it and also reinstalled it completely but still does not work.

Comment: Make sure you install it as Admin, and that the path specified in the shot is a valid path that you have access to. Just as a precaution....Also, check the install .log file. Finally, try a different .NET Framework version.

Comment: You can remove the hidden .vs folder in the project folder and re-launch your Visual Studio to check if the error disappears or not.

Answer (score 2):

Hum, I am running 17.3.4, and it works just fine.

I would consider doing a repair - see if that helps.

tools->get tools and features.

You get this:

[image]

(it actually opens two pages). So close the above form, and then you get this:

[image]

So, try the repair.

I suppose ensuring that previous (legacy) templates are also installed would help, but first try a repair.

## Edit: Installing legacy templates

Ok, in comments it was asked what additional install(s) is one to select.

From VS menu tools->get tools and features.

You get/see this:

In above, expand the "ASP.NET and web development" on the right

this:

[image]

And then select these:
(can't remember which exactly from above gets you everything, but given doing legacy development, good idea to select all that I pointed out).

[image]

Comment: "ensuring that previous (legacy) templates are also installed" - how is this done, and which templates do I need?

Comment: See my edit - I show which options to install in my edit above.