# Visual Studio 2022, every new VB project, Properties>Compile gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Even after repairing, then uninstalling & reinstalling, when I create a new project with Visual Studio 2022 (which I just downloaded yesterday -- have been using Visual Studio 2017 until then), then go to `Project` > `{project name} Properties` > `Compile`, I get the error

> An error occurred trying to load the page.
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This occurs with ***every*** project I've created -- all of which are created using the button on the opening screen "Create a new project" > Windows Forms App (.NET Framework).

Things that have been tried without effect:

- running the program using "Run as Administrator"
- deleting the files shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34085345/7106170)
- repairing the Visual Studio installation (and restarting the computer)
- uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio (and restarting the computer)
- adding some code, saving, and running the project (which as a basic "Hello World" project runs fine) before going to Properties
- going to Properties before adding ***any*** code
- [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73846692/visual-studio-2022-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) -- it's about ASP.net, shows a different error (that thread has a pop-up error; mine is simply in the page itself, as shown below), and basically suggests a solution of (a) reinstall -- done that, and (b) some things specific to ASP.net that don't apply in my case.

Other info that may or may not be relevant:

- I'm running on Windows 7 (while VS 2022 has some advertised limitations while running on Windows 7, this isn't one of them... and I don't intend to switch to Windows 10)
- ample disk space available (hundreds of GB)
- Various .NET frameworks produce the same error; generally using 4.7.2
- Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit), Version 17.4.4

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

The info copied from the "About Microsoft Visual Studio" info from the Help menu is:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.4.4
> VisualStudio.17.Release/17.4.4+33213.308 Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.8.03761
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.4.326.54890 ASP.NET and Web Tools
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.4.326.54890 Azure App Service
> Tools v3.0.0
>
> C# Tools   4.4.0-6.22608.27+af1e46ad38d900023f8b1a2839484e471ece1502
> C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
> Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> NuGet Package Manager   6.4.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
> For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
>
> TypeScript Tools   17.0.10921.2001 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft
> Visual Studio
>
> Visual Basic Tools
> 4.4.0-6.22608.27+af1e46ad38d900023f8b1a2839484e471ece1502 Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual F# Tools
> 17.4.0-beta.22512.4+525d5109e389341bb90b144c24e2ad1ceec91e7b Microsoft Visual F# Tools
>
> Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2 AI-assisted development for Visual
> Studio.

I've searched on Stack Overflow and elsewhere for things to try, and nothing seems to fix the issue.  The closest anything came was a Microsoft help forum where an MS employee gave somebody with a similar situation the advice "your Visual Studio installation may be corrupt, so you may have to repair or even uninstall/reinstall it" (sorry, lost the link).  And I tried each of those, but the issue persists.

What can be done to remove this error message and access the Compile settings from a project's Properties?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it was fixed by doing Windows Update including .NET Framework update.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution in the link below, you can try deleting the project's .vs and bin/obj folders and reloading the project.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/project-properties-cannot-open-compile-tab/1690795